# Can't Edit Music Metadata On Samba Share

Tags: permissions, samba, metadata, id3

I have a music library shared over samba. I connect to the samba share with an account that has rwx permissions. I'm able to verify that I can create files in the same directory as the music files as well as rename the music files.

```
[23:18]myuser@mydesktop:~
$ cd /run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share\:server\=myserver\,share\=music%20on%20myserver/Artist\ Name/\[1997\]\ Album\ Title/
[23:20]myuser@PyramidMines:/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=music%20on%20myserver/Artist Name/[1997] Album Title
$ touch newfile
[23:20]myuser@PyramidMines:/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=music%20on%20myserver/Artist Name/[1997] Album Title
$ ls -al
total 149035
drwx------ 1 myuser myuser        0 Feb 15 22:37 .
drwx------ 1 myuser myuser        0 Nov 27 13:36 ..
-rwx------ 1 myuser myuser 39574560 Nov 27 13:06 01 Song Title.mp3
-rwx------ 1 myuser myuser 43185728 Nov 27 13:08 02 Song Title.mp3
-rwx------ 1 myuser myuser 69753303 Nov 27 13:13 03 Song Title.mp3
-rwx------ 1 myuser myuser    46015 Nov 27 13:06 cover (1).jpg
-rwx------ 1 myuser myuser    51128 Nov 27 13:06 cover.jpg
[23:20]myuser@PyramidMines:/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=music%20on%20myserver/Artist Name/[1997] Album Title
$ mv 01\ Song\ Title.mp3 01SongTitle.mp3
[23:21]myuser@PyramidMines:/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=music%20on%20myserver/Artist Name/[1997] Album Title
$ mv 01SongTitle.mp3 01\ Song\ Title.mp3
[23:21]myuser@PyramidMines:/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=music%20on%20myserver/Artist Name/[1997] Album Title
$ rm newfile
```

I've tried now with a number of applications, EasyTag, Clementine and MusicBrainz Picard, to edit the meta-data of some mislabelled songs but they all return an error.

For instance when I try to update the Artist on a song in Clementine.

```
An error occurred writing metadata to '/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=music%20on%20myserver/Artist Name/[1997] Album Title/02 Song Name.mp3'
```

Similar errors came back from EasyTag and Picard. I've already used Picard to update the files in question before I moved them to the samba share. I realized after that MusicBrainz had a misspelled Artist for some of my albums which is what I'm trying to update now.

At this point it looks like I'm going to have to copy the albums to my desktop, edit them and put them back on the share.

I've checked to make sure that Picard/Clementine are actually running as `myuser` so they should have my privileges on those shared files?

I don't think it's an issue in my `smb.conf`

```
[Music on myserver]
path = /path/to/Music
browseable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = yes
valid users = mediamanager, streamer
write list = mediamanager
```

Mounting the share on my desktop with the `mediamanager` account.

---

Update:

Does anyone have any idea? The only thing I can think of is that the id3 tagging programs used by Clementine, EasyTag, etc. aren't properly handling the path to file string
`/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=music%20on%20myserver/Artist Name/[1997] Album Title/02 Song Name.mp3`

I know when I tried to open up one of the samba share folders with pyRenamer it tells me the directory is invalid.

---

Update:

Perhaps some progress.

I installed id3 and attempted to modify a tag using the command line, I haven't been able to come up with any useful diagnostics from the other programs as of yet.

```
[20:25]myuser@mydesktop:~
$ cd /run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=music%20on%20myserver/Artist Name/[1993] Album Name/

[20:27]myuser@mydesktop:/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=music%20on%20myserver/Artist Name/[1993] Album Name
$ id3 -l 01\ Song\ Name.mp3 
01 Song Name.mp3:
Title  : Song Name                       Artist: Artist Name                   
Album  : Album Name                      Year:     , Genre: Rock (17)
Comment:                                 Track: 1

[20:27]myuser@mydesktop:/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=music%20on%20myserver/Artist Name/[1993] Album Name
$ id3 -y "1993" 01\ Song\ Name.mp3 
id3: fopen: 01 Song Name.mp3: Operation not supported
```

So the question has become, why isn't fopen supported on the shared files?

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 3):

I haven't exactly found an answer but did come up with a workaround.

Previously I wasn't mounting the Samba shares on startup, I had browsed to those shares through Nautilus via 'Connect to Server'. After connecting to them once I bookmarked the locations and mounted them by opening Nautilus and clicking on the bookmark. This would automatically mount the share to `/run/user/1001/.....`

I liked that solution because it meant I wasn't auto-mounting shares that I wasn't planning on accessing.

I was however able to edit the meta-tags after remounting the share to more of a normal path.

`sudo mount -t cifs -o user=mediamanager //myserver/music\ on\ myserver /home/myuser/Music/Music\ on\ Myserver`

My guess is that the id3 tag editing tools weren't able to handle the path name `/run/user/1001/gvfs/smb-share:server=myserver,share=music%20on%20myserver/` but I'm not certain. As I've shown above, even when I manually navigated to a folder containing mp3's id3 failed, I'm not sure the path should have any effect there.

For now it appears that if I want to edit any meta-tags I will have to either manually mount the shares when I need to or have them auto-mounted via fstab.